# Component or Source for Running an FTP Server via C# (with SSL)

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ftp, ftps

I'm surprised by the lack of products out there for running your own FTP server in managed code. I'm looking for either a product or thorough source code for building an FTP server in C# that supports SSL. I need complete control over the directory/file handling, not just serving files from a local directory.

[Clever Internet .NET Suite](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/inetsuitenet/suitenet.asp) looks to be exactly what I'm looking for. However, when I tried it out I got errors connecting to the FtpServerSSL sample from FileZilla when SSL was enabled. It worked perfectly without SSL, so I wrote to their support, but I haven't heard a response from them yet.

Answer (score 0):

We plan to release FTP / FTPS server components within a month as part of our SecureBlackbox product. The components are currently being internally tested. As SecureBlackbox is a security suite, SSL part will work there :).

Comment: Cool -- my specific needs are pretty immediate, but I would be very interested in hearing more when the product is ready for release.

Answer (score 0):

Never done it myself, but you could try one of these:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/FTPServerinCSharp11162005015958AM/FTPServerinCSharp.aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7409/

You secure the port using httpcfg or netsh in windows, not in the app.